# vb.net reading delimited files with text qualifiers

Tags: vb.net, text-files

Is there a set function in vb.net that allows you to read a delimited file with text qualifiers?  in the past i have used the split command but that does not allow you to take into account the text qualifiers.

Comment: [Split Function that Supports Text Qualifiers](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15361/Split-Function-that-Supports-Text-Qualifiers)

Answer (score 3):

The [TextFieldParser class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.aspx) is intended to handle this directly, provided the text qualifiers are quotation marks (see the [HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.hasfieldsenclosedinquotes.aspx) option).